# Interactive grid throws ORA-01858 on Update (19.1)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have just started using Apex and want a simple Interactive Grid to show users and allow them to update data.

There are lots of columns with Order Date as a primary key (with Order Number as second column in PK).

I get Ajax threw error ORA-01858 when I update one of the rows.

I have created a test table with just a date as primary key and a number as an updateable column:

```
create table xxx_date2 as select trunc(sysdate) + level as d1, level as col2 from dual  connect by level <= 10 ;

alter table xxx_date2 add constraint xxx_date2_pk primary key (d1);
```

When I try and update Col2 [Edit: changing the Col2 value and hitting "Save" on the IG toolbar] I get the error. I have created a similar table with number as PK and it is fine.

Main assumption is that it is to do with Date formats / time portions? Maybe I can trunc() or format the date somehow....?

Can anyone offer any help? I am very new to Apex and lost where to look.

[UPDATE: I have made the Primary Key ROWID in the Apex page. This seems have fixed my problem. My hypothesis is that the date is now not being re-formatted by Apex as part of the update statement.
I would still like to understand what is/might be happening though so I can build a page using whatever attributes I choose]

Comment: Which is the UPDATE you are executing?

Comment: Hi - sorry I don't get your meaning - When I have a list of rows with Date | Quantity I change the Quantity and get this numeric error. (I experimented with truncating the date in the test table and got No Data Found errors. I don't want to confuse the issue but this points towards the date format being the issue).

Comment: You said "When I try and update Col2 I get the error", which is the UPDATE sentence you're executing?

Comment: Is there a way to trap the SQL that APex issues? As far as I know it would issue "Update xxx_date set col2=999 where d1 = '29-AUG-2019' (I would wrap that in  to_date if I was writing it by hand.

Comment: I thought you was updating from the "SQL Workshop" typing the UPDATE manually. You can trap de SQL by tracing the session.

Comment: This is possibly a bug. If you are new to apex then I would not focus on getting this to work because you'll lose a ton of time, get frustrated and miss out on a ton of fun. Using a date as primary key isn't a very good practice. I'd suggest using a identity column as primary key in addition to the 2 columns you currently have and use that column as primary key column. Then recreate your interactive grid.

Comment: Cheers @KoenLostrie. - I did update to say that I'd switched to using ROWID as the PK on this form. Is that bad practice? I can create a true surrogate key on the db if necessary. I do remember from my Forms days long ago that dates were pretty awful to work with as keys. I wouldn't usually consider using a date as a key but am forced into it in this case.

Comment: Using ROWID as PK in the interactive grid should be fine. Definitely not a bad practice.